# Calculating heat current through a spherical shell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

I have a spherical shell with inner radius $a$ and outer radius $b>a$. There is a temperature difference of $\Delta T$ between the inner and outer shells. The thermal conductivity is $k$. The problem is to calculate the heat current, $H=\frac{\textrm{d}Q}{\textrm{d}t}$.

I know that
$$H=\frac{kA\Delta T}{L},$$
in the idealized scenario of two insulated systems attached with a rod with conductivity $k$, length $L$, and cross-sectional area $A$.

To solve this problem, I attempted to generalize this to
$$H=\frac{k\Delta T}{b-a}\int_a^b{\frac{\textrm{d}A}{\textrm{d}r}\textrm{ d}r}=4\pi k\Delta T(a+b).$$

I am not sure that this is the correct answer. In fact, [this source](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/heat-current-through-a-spherical-shell.84469/) says that it is not. It claims that the correct answer is:
$$H=\frac{4\pi kab\Delta T}{b-a},$$
and I am unable to follow the reasoning of the response provided. Where have I went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: I was under the impression that such questions were allowed as long as effort was shown in prior working and consultation of outside sources.

Comment: [This response](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6097/210029) says that I may post questions along the lines of "where did I go wrong" as opposed to "is this is correct" which is what I did.

Comment: In any case, is there a way this can be reworded to be reopened?